# Job not found in JobRegistry

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to stop the spring batch execution. I have tried

```
jobExecution.stop();
jobRepository.update(jobExecution);
```

has no effect on the job.

When i tried

```
jobOperator.stop(JOB_EXECUTION_ID);
```

i am getting NoSuchJobException. I am new to Spring Batch. Can anyone explain why i am getting NoSuchJobException?

After some debugging, I have found that Job is not found in JobRegistry. JobExplorer and JobRepository are able to find the job. Is there any specific configuration required for JobRegistry.

```
07:22:27.625  WARN o.s.b.c.l.s.SimpleJobOperator            : Cannot find Job object in the job registry. StoppableTasklet#stop() will not be called org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [wf-demo-1552486941361] was registered
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.getJob(MapJobRegistry.java:66) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator.stop(SimpleJobOperator.java:403) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
```

is the error stack

Comment: You have to Specify the JOB_EXECUTION_ID.  jobOperator.stop(executionId);  In Spring Batch, Once Job is Initiate by the Tasklet ,will create one Job ID.

Comment: :) I am passing the JOB_EXECUTION_ID as a param.

Comment: There by Debug the issue and confirm the Job ID is been assign to JOB_EXECUTION_ID constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `JobExecution.stop`, it will be removed in a future version (See [BATCH-1987](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1987)).

`JobOperator#stop(jobExecutionId)` is the way to go. The error `NoSuchJobFoundException` is not a Spring Batch exception, so I don't know what is means. The closest exception I can think of is `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobExecutionException` which is thrown by the job operator if it can't find an execution with the given id. Make sure you are passing a valid job execution id to the `stop` method.

Answer (score 1):

This code helps me

```
@Bean
public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor() {
    JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
    postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
    return postProcessor;
}
```

Read docs about [JobRegistry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#jobregistry)